# month in datepicker has wrong regional name

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, datepicker

I using datepickers like this.

It using language great, instead of title

I get to language file and see this

> monthNames: [ "januari","februari","mars","april","maj","juni",
>       "juli","augusti","september","oktober","november","december" ],

But in title I get this

[image]

What is wrong and how I can fix this?

```
 export function load_datepickers_inline(): void {
     const search_legs_0_datepicker = $("#search_legs_0_datepicker");
     const leg_0_datepicker = $("#search_legs_0_datepicker").datepicker({
         language: gon.locale,
         classes: 'inline-picker',
         altField: '#search_legs_0_date',
         defaultDate: new Date(search_legs_0_datepicker.attr("data-defaultDate")),
         minDate: new Date(search_legs_0_datepicker.attr('data-mindate')),
         maxDate: new Date(search_legs_0_datepicker.attr('data-maxdate')),
         altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
         onSelect: (dateText, inst) => {
             const date = new Date(dateText);
             if (!leg_0_datepicker) {
                 return false;
             }
             leg_1_datepicker.datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
             if ($("#search_legs_0_hotel_date").length > 0) {
                 $('#search_legs_0_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').update('minDate', date);
                 $('#search_legs_0_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').datepicker("setDate", date);
                 $('#search_legs_1_hotel_date').datepicker().data('datepicker').update('minDate', date);
             }
         }
     })
```

Comment: What is the value of `gon.locale`?

Comment: se-SV as console says @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: What does it say instead? Are there any errors? I can't load images so not sure what it on it.

Comment: That's not a supported locale. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n. Assuming you're trying to localise Swedish, try just `sv`

Comment: `https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/i18n/datepicker-sv.js`

Comment: Thank's understood @RoryMcCrossan